# How can I implement a verified field in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

In Django I'd like to add a field "verified" of type `BooleanField` to my models which shall indicate if the current model instance has been reviewed by a staff user member or not. Whenever a model instance field other than the "verified" field changed the verified field value shall be reset to `False`. Whenever only the "verified" field has been changed it's value shall be taken as is (most of the time `True` but potentially `False` as well).

One possibility would be to reset the "verified" field in [`post-save` signals handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) considering [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) passed to `save()`. However using signals seems to be considered an anti-pattern in almost all use cases. Instead one should override the `save()` method. But still when overriding `save` I'd have to determine `update_fields` manually somehow. Otherwise I've no information about which fields changed.

How can I implement something like this most easily. I'd prefer a solution using a third-party package w.o. custom hacks or a solution without any dependencies to other packages. However using [`django-model-utils monitorfield`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#monitorfield), [`django-dirtyfields`](https://django-dirtyfields.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) for a custom implementation or something equivalent would be ok as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dirty-fields` seems to be easiest to implement a verified field. So far I came up with something like follows:

**DJANGO-APP/models.py**:

```py
from django.db import models
from dirtyfields import DirtyFieldsMixin


class VerifiedModel(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    """
    Abstract class which allows to extend models with user verification model field.
    """
    ENABLE_M2M_CHECK = True
    verified = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text="The verification status. True means meta-data is verified. False means meta-data is not verified. The verification status is reset to False whenever a field is set.",
    )

    def _update_verified_field(self):
        """
        To be called in inheriting model's save() method.
        """
        if self.is_dirty():
            if not 'verified' in self.get_dirty_fields():
                self.verified = False

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelToBeVerified(VerifiedModel):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self._update_verified_field()
        return super(ModelToBeVerified, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```